# IntelliJ 2018.3.6 doesn't recognise gradle tasks and properties

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

Hi I have problem with new version of IntelliJ it has problems with recognizing tasks arguments. For example it doesn't recognize "processResources" or "bootJar" but for example java plugin for bootJar is loaded properly ( I also checked in classpath). It also doesn't recognize arguments in tasks, saying "cannot infer argument types". But in console given tasks works.
Here are printscreens with errors.

[bootJar error and classpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyAJp.png)

[processResources etc.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fDeq.png)

Is it possible to fix it somehow? It's very misleading.

Comment: Try 2019.1 latest version from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download and re-import project. It contains related improvements.

Comment: Yup, right at the time it helped :)